# What's my optimal choice for remote access to my localhost sites?

Tags: plugins

I need tech support from a plugin vendor and they need remote access. I am running the latest versions of WordPress with Elementor on a Windows 10 machine and host using localhost. Specifically I am using Laragon.

A Laragon URL to load the site locally typically looks like this: sitename.local:8080. Laragon provides native support for remote access by means of ngrok called by a menu selection used to "share."

So I installed the free version of ngrok. I used Laragon to share and Laragon calls ngrok that gives me a URL to use for 8 hours. I test the ngrok URL from another remote machine and it loads and I login to the website. Then ngrok bombs out because WordPress/Elementor are generated too many HTTP requests.

The free ngrok plan supports "40 connections/minute" and the next two paid tiers of service support "40 connections/minute."

My question is "Do we have a plugin or any other means to determine how many connections our localhost website is generating before paying for ngrok?" They do offer 15 day payment return but I'd actually like to know how many connections are being made as it may help provide insights regarding performance.

Finally, the big question: "What is my optimal choice for providing remote access to my websites running on localhost?"

Comment: The Browser built-in developer tools will help you:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: Yes, that'a a reminder how to count HTTP requests when a site is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This isnt a direct answer, but maybe can solve your problem.
Why just dont open a port on your router to the local server?!

I use apache2 has localserver and apache2 uses port 80 as default and also most routers to get access to internet in this case the router doesnt open any port at port 80 because is being already use by the router, but for example my mysql server database uses a different port, so to mysql database I only need to open a port in my rooter and anyone in the world with the credentials can access this database, if your server uses a different port (normally port 80) than your router, like mysql server you can just open a port in your internet router, then anyone whith your ip, the port you set on the router and the credentials can get access.

examples:

my localhost access path:  localhost/name_of_website

if I open a router port on for example 3321 and my home ip is 2222.33333.5555

I can acess the same address from anywhere with 2222.33333.5555:3321/name_of_website

If your local server uses the port 80 or 4 like mine, the process is a little more complex. but it is possible!
Now for direct programs that do that automatically, I do not know names!

One other way, maybe not so preferable is for example use a remote assistance software like TeamViewer or Microsoft Remote Assist.